# how to sort using KnpPaginator paginate() method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, knppaginator

I'm trying to sort some data using KnpPaginator, but there is no example of how to use "options" array.
For now I sort data, by passing it to the findBy itself, but I can't sort by subobject attribute this way.

```
$this->limit    = $request->query->getInt('limit', $container->getParameter('pagination.default_limit'));
$this->page     = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
$sortColumn     = $this->camelcase($request->query->get('sort', 'id'));
$sortDirection  = $request->query->get('direction', 'asc');
$this->sort     = array($sortColumn => $sortDirection);
$this->list     = $this->getRepo(Service::class)->findBy(
    array('user' => $this->getUser()->getId()),
    $this->sort   
);
$pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
    $this->list,
    $this->page,
    $this->limit
);
```

It works totally fine when I want to sort by one of Service columns but I want to sort it by `Service->getType()->getName()` property.
Service has type property which is ManyToOne relation to ServiceType.
ServiceType uses DoctrineBehaviors Translatable, so column name belongs to other object named ServiceTypeTranslation.
I'd like to use its full functionality without having to write DQL myself, but when I try to name sort like "type.name" I get error that this column doesn't exist.
Eager loading wouldn't help as it only joins 1 table and translation for "name" property resides 2 tables deep from Service.
I know that I could try using $options array as 4th argument for paginate() but I can't get it to work.
Any ideas? Below some parts of Entities for visualisation.

Service.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Service
{

...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DictServiceType", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

...
```

ServiceType.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DictServiceType
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

...


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->translate(null, false)->getName();
    }

...
```

ServiceTypeTranslation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DictServiceTypeTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

...
```

For the record, I tried to use paginator like this, based on what I read in the paginate() method description, but it's not even close to working.
There are no examples of how to use the $whitelist array anywhere, at least I couldn't find them.

```
$pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
            $this->list,
            $this->page,
            $this->limit,
            array(
                array(
                    $this->sort
                )
            )
        );
```

And the phpdoc for this 4th argument says:

> ```
>  * @param array $options - less used options:
>  *     boolean $distinct - default true for distinction of results
>  *     string $alias - pagination alias, default none
>  *     array $whitelist - sortable whitelist for target fields being paginated
> ```